# Determine a camera relative position which is inside a second camera FOV using video footage

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, camera

Here is a two moving camera setup:

[image: camera setup]

The points are the cameras and the half-rectangle the field of view of each. Both cameras got the same parameters and are placed at the same height from the ground. The dotted lines indicate the path of each camera. They follow approximately the same path, stay close to each other but one may pass the other and vice versa. So they will share many key points. For each camera I have a video, the videos are synchronised. The object that carries this camera is not visible on the frames of the other camera.

If we consider that *camera 2* is in the field of view of *camera 1* and that we can analyse two or more frames from each camera. How can I determine the relative position of *camera 2* at a given time *t* in a frame of *camera 1* at the same time *t*?
By position in a frame I mean coordinates *(x,y)* but also *z* (depth) which could be represented in the 2D frame by the size of the point at position *(x,y)*. It would be a plus if we could also determine the angle of rotation of *camera 2* relative to *camera 1*.

The application would be for onboard videos of Formula 1 between drivers. An example is provided just below:

[image: application example]

I don't know where to begin, I know it will probably involve depth generation or maybe even 3D reconstruction. I have seen research papers on overlapping fields of view from multiple cameras but this was used for object detection.

I hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: If you can assume that both cameras have the same intrinsics (e.g. undistort and change virtual intrinsics) there is an opencv function to get the camera motion between two images from a homography that describes the transformation between both images. There will be 4 possible solutions. The other way to start from would be epoipolar to take some readings about epipolar geometry.

Comment: @Micka Thanks, unfortunately I don't know the intrinsics and openCV function requires them. Furthermore, it needs a pattern and I can't find a suitable one for a car moving around a track since it's almost always a continuous white line on the sides except in corner. 
I will take a look at epipolar geometry.

Comment: can _you as a human_ tell where those cameras/cars are on the track? if you have trouble, a computer should have too. those pictures are way too close-cropped (lack of environment). the pavement is the most boring thing to point a camera at.

Comment: @Torpedo without intrinsics you will probably have a very hard time with any method.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz By analyzing the two videos side by side, yes I could determine a car position relatively to the other but not the exact position on track. Btw the footage are a bit less cropped in reality than the one I put in the post, see: https://i.imgur.com/QApoDwc.jpg

Comment: @Micka Maybe I could calibrate one time by calculating manually real length of different horizontal lines on the image?

Comment: well then, your task is SLAM/SfM

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks, do you know how I can take in account the speed of the car (I got the data) in these kind of methods to improve results?

Comment: Kalman filters or something. you are operating in the field of robotics. read all about it.